# Problem when defining Int as an instance of a type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, instance, typeclass

I am trying to define `Int` as an instance of my type class `Add`.
I wanted to define my own operator `+++`, which should be overloaded on integers and strings. My goal was to be able to add integers and concatenate strings with the same operator. Therefore i created the type class `Add` with the instances `Int` and `[char]`:

```
class Add a where
    (+++) :: a -> a -> a

instance Add Int where
    x +++ y = x + y

instance Add [char] where
    x +++ y = x ++ y
```

**Problem: When evaluating the expression `1 +++ 2`, GHCi gives me the following error message:**

```
<interactive>:9:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 18 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

But when defining `Integer` as an instance of `Add`

```
instance Add Integer where
    x +++ y = x + y
```

GHCi can evaluate `1 +++ 2` to `3` and i don't get an error.

**Question: Why is it not working, when using `Int` as an instance? What is the difference in using `Int` or `Integer`?**

Comment: The problem isn't that it doesn't work, the problem is that it could work in more than one way and the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

Comment: i just found a similar question to this with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824047/haskell-yesno-type-class-why-integer

Comment: Kind of orthogonal to your question, but: please don't write `instance Add [char]`. This happens to work, but for a misleading reason that I'm not sure you're aware of: `char`, being lowercase, is a _type variable_. I.e. this instance actually works for lists of _any_ type, not just character ones. To make this clear, simply write it `instance Add [a]`. —Or, if you really want this instance to be `Char`-specific, write `instance Add [Char]` (w/ `-XFlexibleInstances`) or `instance (c ~ Char) => Add [c]` (requires `-XGADTs` or `-XTypeFamilies`). [These behave differently!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that it works for `Integer` but not `Int`, I'm fairly sure this is due to "type defaulting".

In GHCi (and to a lesser extent in compiled code), if an expression has an ambiguous type, the compiler tries several "default types", which of which is `Integer` (but *not* `Int`). That's almost certainly where the difference is coming from.

I suspect if you add `:: Int` to the end of your expression, it will execute just fine. The problem isn't that there's a type *error*, it's that more than one type potentially fits, and the compiler isn't sure which one you intended.

I've never tried this, but I believe you can change the defaults by saying something like `default (Int, Double)`. (Usually it's `default (Integer, Double)`.) I think that's the right syntax; not 100% sure.

There's a bit about this in the GHCi manual: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci

Also the Haskell Report: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3 (Section 4.3.4)

Comment: yes, thank you. Adding :: Int at the end of 1 +++ 2 would work

Comment: FWIW, I'm rather fond of `default ()`, because I generally don't want any defaulting. But default to `Int` is pretty reasonable if you want to use `(^)` a lot.